# How to suppress a glossary page number for an individual entry?

Tags: page-numbering, glossaries

In my glossary I want to refer to other glossary items, but I do not want these links to appear in the indexed pages.

Here is my preamble (edited so there might be something missing from it)

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{book}
% hyperref setup
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks,allcolors=blue}

% Glossaies

% Orig stuff
\usepackage[xindy,toc]{glossaries} % see http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Glossary
\renewcommand{\glsnamefont}[1]{\makefirstuc{#1}} % causes capitalisation of the first letter of each word in the glossary (http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=9966)

% Dual Entries part
% 2= Label, 3 = abbreviation, 4= Long form, 5=description 
\newcommand*{\newdualentry}[5][]{%
\newglossaryentry{gls-#2}{name={#4},%
    text={#4\protect\glsadd{#2}},%
    description={#5},%
    #1
}%
\newacronym{#2}{#3\protect\glsadd{gls-#2}}{See \gls{gls-#2}}
}

\makeglossaries
\include{Glossary}
\begin{document}
}
```

And here is an example of a glossary entry

```
\newacronym{PCMRI}{PC-MRI}{Time-resolved Phase Contrast \gls{MRI}}
\newacronym{MRI}{MRI}{Magnetic Resonance Imaging}
\newglossaryentry{4DPCMRI}
{
    name = 4D PC-MRI,
    description = {Flow sensitive \gls{PCMRI} with velocity encoding in 3 directions acquired at a single plane or as an image stack}
}
```

At the moment, the PCMRI and MRI term entries are page numbers where they appear in the glossary are being listed, but I want them to only be listed if they appear in the main body of text.

Comment: If I understand right, you say that the glossary page number is shown beside the MRI and PCMRI. If that is the case the problem comes from the fact that your are using \gls{MRI} and \gls{PCMRI} inside your glossary. If you remove the two \gls{} that should fix your problem.

Comment: If you don't want a hyperlink, just use `\glsentrytext{PCMRI}`, or if you do want a hyperlink (but not index that reference) use `\glshyperlink{PCMRI}`